# A question about [UIViewController alloc] 

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, interface-builder

I am going through some sample code from Apple. The following 5 statements are from MoveMeAppDelegate.m belonging to the "MoveMe" sample project:

```
UIViewController *aViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MoveMeView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];

self.viewController = aViewController;
[aViewController release];

UIView *controllersView = [viewController view];
[window addSubview:controllersView];
```

From documentation, @"MoveMeView" defines the name of a xib file.  But it seems that a xib file can have more than one view object. And in the last statement above, the controllersView is added to a window object.  My question is if the window has more than one view, then how does the compiler know which view is the above codes referring to ?

Comment: Just FYI, the compiler has nothing to do with it. It's the UIKit runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking how your app knows which view is the controller's view: in your .xib file, you "attach" one of the views to the controller. This relationship is called an outlet, and in code is signified by the `IBOutlet` tag on an instance variable or on a property.

For more information, check out Apple's Resource Programming Guide--specifically, [the section](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/LoadingResources/CocoaNibs/CocoaNibs.html) entitled "Nib Files."

If you're asking how the window knows which views belong to it: a window on iOS is also a view, and can have a (nearly) unlimited number of subviews.

If you're asking something else... I don't know what you're asking, so please clarify.

Comment: I think your IBOutlet part in your reply answered the question.  But it would take more reading into the documentation to fully understand the process.  Just also want to ask if a single view controller can handle a view and all its possible subviews ?

Comment: @Stanley You'll benefit a lot from reading this guide: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/